# Optimisation suggestions for the amicable numbers algorithm

Tags: c

I've encountered a high time complexity issue in my algorithm for finding pairs of amicable numbers. Although the input is capped at 10000, it takes 3 minutes to find all the pairs.

How can I optimize the code below?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumofdiv(int);
void amicable_nums(int);

int main()
{
  int limit;
  printf("Enter the limit to check amicable numbers: ");
  scanf("%d", &limit);
  amicable_nums(limit);
  return 0;
}

void amicable_nums(int limit)
{
  int num1, num2, sum1, sum2;
  for(num1=220; num1<limit; num1++)
  {
    if ((num1%2 != 0) && (num1%3 != 0) && (num1%5 != 0))//prime number detection (odd num > 220, so number 2, for example, that is prime doesn't count), prime number can't be amicable
    {
      continue;
    }
    for (num2 = num1+1; num2<limit; num2++)
    {
      if ((num1%2==0 && num2%2 != 0) || (num1%2 != 0 && num2%2 == 0))//only both odd or even numbers can be amicable
      {
        continue;
      }
      if ((num2%2 != 0) && (num2%3 != 0) && (num2%5 != 0))//the same prime number detection as before
      {
        continue;
      }
      sum1 = sumofdiv(num1);
      if (sum1 != num2)//if the sum of proper divisors of the first number is NOT equal to the second number, there is no reason to check the sum of proper divisors of the second number
      {
        continue;
      }
      sum2 = sumofdiv(num2);
      if (sum1 == num2 && sum2 == num1 && num1 != num2)
      {
        printf("(%d, %d)\n", num1, num2);
      }
    }
  }
}

int sumofdiv(int num)
{
  int div, sum = 0, even_limit = num/2, odd_limit = num/3;
  if (num%2 == 0)
  {
    for (div=1; div<even_limit; div++)
    {
      if ((num%div) == 0)
      {
        sum += div;
      }
    }
    sum += even_limit;
  }
  else
  {
    for (div=1; div<odd_limit; div+=2)//odd number can't be divided by even number
    {
      if ((num%div) == 0)
      {
        sum += div;
      }
    }
    sum += odd_limit;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

**P.S.:** there are some comments in the code for several statements.
I've tried to avoid prime numbers and avoided computing a lot of numbers that can't be amicable by default; computing is still slow, however. I also make more jumps of num1 or/and num2 in the nested for loop, but it outputs less pairs than it has to be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because _[Code Improvement questions are generally too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349513/are-code-improvement-questions-allowed)_, and can be better addressed at the _[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)_ stack exchange

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm has a time complexity greater than **O(N<sup>3</sup>)** because for each `num1`, you try most values of `num2` and the computation of `sumofdiv()` also has linear complexity.

You can drastically reduce this complexity by testing only a single value per iteration: You have a pair of amicable numbers if `sumofdiv(sumofdiv(num1)) == num1)`.

Here is a simplistic but effective implementation:

```
void amicable_nums(int limit) {
    int num1, num2;
    for (num1 = 1; num1 < limit; num1++) {
        num2 = sumofdiv(num1);
        if (num2 > num1 && sumofdiv(num2) == num1) {
            printf("(%d, %d)\n", num1, num2);
        }
    }
}
```

On my system, the time for scanning up to 10000 is reduced from 71 seconds to less than 100 milliseconds.  Note also how simple and generic the code is: no special cases are tested.

Your function `sumofdiv()` can be simplified and accelerated too, providing another factor of 10 speed improvement (for 10000), for a final complexity slightly above **O(N<sup>1.5</sup>)**.

Here is the improved code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sumofdiv(int num) {
    int div, sum = 1;

    for (div = 2; div * div <= num; div++) {
        if (num % div == 0) {
            int quo = num / div;
            sum += div;
            if (quo != div)
                sum += quo;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

void amicable_nums(int limit) {
    int num1, num2;
    for (num1 = 1; num1 < limit; num1++) {
        num2 = sumofdiv(num1);
        if (num2 > num1 && sumofdiv(num2) == num1) {
            printf("(%d, %d)\n", num1, num2);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int limit;
    if (argc > 1) {
        /* this is optional, for testing purposes */
        limit = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        printf("Enter the limit to check amicable numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &limit);
    }
    amicable_nums(limit);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
~/dev/stackoverflow > time ./amicable 10000
(220, 284)
(1184, 1210)
(2620, 2924)
(5020, 5564)
(6232, 6368)

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Further tests produce 13 pairs up to 100000 in 122ms, 42 pairs up to 1000000 in 3.6 seconds and 108 pairs up to 10000000 in 2 minutes.

Comment: Won't  your code find each pair of amicable numbers twice?

Comment: It does, but that's easy to fix.

Comment: The first suggestion with the amicable_nums function is great, how didn't I think about it before. Thanks! The second one is invalid, in this particular task it's not allowed for me to use command-line arguments.

Comment: @Asm. The command line argument parsing is just for ease of testing, it is not a suggestion for your optimisation goal. The revised code for `sumofdiv` does improve the efficiency by a large factor too.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your solution:

1) Build [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for faster number factorization

2) Factorize each number once and keep sum of it's prime factors in an array

3) Having factored a number, do the following:

```
   if (sum_of_prime_factors < n) {
     if (arr[sum_of_prime_factors] == n){
       // ... pair found ...
     }
   }
```

Comment: In this particular task it's not allowed to use arrays (i'm CS student), only functions and if-else statements are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

A big (big as in, [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) optimization would be on your [sumofdiv](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-of-all-proper-divisors-of-a-natural-number/) function. You loop all the way to `n`. For every pair of factors `a <= b`of `n`, the smaller factor `a` is less than or equal to `sqrt(n)`. The other factor `b` is just equal to `n/a`. Use that to help you write the function in just a loop to `sqrt(n)`.

To help you even more, look at where `sumofdiv(num1)` is. Do you really need to calculate it inside the `for (num2 = num1+1; num2<limit; num2++)` loop? Try putting it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

A small optimisation.

What about changing this code

```
for (num2 = num1+1; num2<limit; num2++)
{
  if ((num1%2==0 && num2%2 != 0) || (num1%2 != 0 && num2%2 == 0))
  {
    continue;
  }
...
```

to

```
for (num2 = num1+2; num2<limit; num2+=2)
{
```

By starting at at num1+2, then num2 starts as even if num1 is even. By incrementing by 2, we ensuring that num2 stays even if num1 is even. Similarly if num1 is odd, we ensure num2 is always odd.

Comment: This isn't going to change the runtime. It makes it much prettier, but 99.9(99?)%+ of the time spent in that loop will be in the `sumofdiv` function (even if the function was empty, just the function call would be 90%+ of the time in the loop. `if` statement and then `continue`s are very cheap, 10000-50000 times cheaper than looping 10000 times in `sumofdiv` in fact). I'd recommend putting logic optimizations in the comments.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone I have been thinking about this and I don't believe you're correct in all circumstances. Particularly if the code is being executed in parallel on a warp of light weight processors operating in lock-stop (exactly like on a GPU). In that case every second processor would do nothing, after evaluating the if statement. Which means that you would be losing 50% of your potential processing power.

Answer (score 0):

A big optimisation.
You don't need a double for loop.
If a number is amicable you don't have to check all possible numbers, you only have to check the sum of its factors.

In pseudo code:

```
for i = 220 to max:
    j = sum_of_div(i)
    i_prime = sum_of_div(j)
    if (i == i_prime) and (i < j):
        print i and j are amicable
```